# Unknown Character

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Facing a typical issue of some unknown character.
Actually trying to compile some packages in database through script and got an error as below:
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "?SET DEF..." - rest of line ignored.

When i open the log file in notepad++ it shows the line as shown above.
Now, if I open the same log file in scite editor it shows the same file as:

SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "ï»¿SET DEF..." - rest of line ignored.

Not getting what could be the issue.
Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: What do you see when you look at the script in either editor? Whatever the character is, it shouldn't be in the script before that `set` command?

Comment: There is no character in the script before the set command. In other words the script starts with the set define off command only.

Comment: Not even a hidden control character? Can you view the file as a hex dump and check there's nothing invisible there? Otherwise, how are you  executing it?

Comment: Why not just remove the binary char(s) before SET DEF... in the script? (assuming the rest is fine)  Also, if using Windows, you might try [Textpad](http://textpad.com/products/textpad/features.html) as a text editor, it can show you a hex display to find out what you really have.

Comment: I found the unknown character when I opened the file in hex editor. Edited it and now it runs fine. Thanks @AlexPoole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has an unprintable character at the start (as you discovered from comments), which some editors don't display at all, and others display as an unknown character. `"ï»¿"` is the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark):

> The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the byte sequence
>   0xEF,0xBB,0xBF. A text editor or web browser interpreting the text as
>   ISO-8859-1 or CP1252 will display the characters ï»¿ for this.

From that article some editors (notable Notepad) add that automatically. It should be safe to open the file with a hex editor and remove the extra character, and you'll then be able to run the script normally.